# .NET Core Web API - truly global non-success error code handling with common JSON response schema

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are developing a REST API service in .NET 7. We have a `BaseResponse` class whose examples for successful and unsuccessful states are provided below. Our ultimate goal is to return this same response type for **all REST API responses** (ex. unauthorized access, page not found, exception occurred, controller returned `NotFound()` or `NotFound("error message")`, route does not exist, method not allowed, ...). This way, clients can always apply the same deserializing logic.

`ResponseBase.cs` generic class:

```cs
public class ResponseBase<T> where T : class
{
  public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
  public string Result { get; set; }
  public string Summary { get; set; }
  public List<ErrorDescription> Errors { get; set; }
  public T ResponseData { get; set; }
}
```

Successful response:

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "2024-03-07T12:04:04.6005063Z",
  "Result": "OK",
  "Summary": "Request was successful!",
  "Errors": null,
  "ResponseData": {
    "Name": "John"
  }
}
```

Unsuccessful response:

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "2024-03-07T12:07:29.7723776Z",
  "Result": "ERROR",
  "Summary": "Request was not successful!",
  "Errors": [
    {
      "Key": "RequestData.SerialNumber",
      "Errors": [
        "Serial number must be a positive integer!"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ResponseData": null
}
```

Obviously, there are a lot of resources online which explain how to deal with such scenarios. I especially liked [this article](https://disklosr.com/posts/004-consistent-error-response-format-asp-net-core-web-api/). Their ultimate result for achieving global error handling with common JSON model was the following:

```cs
// Startup.cs
public class StartupBare
{
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddControllers()
      .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(o =>
      {
        // Disable `ClientErrorResultFilter`
        o.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;

        // Custom response format for model validation and binding errors
        o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
        {
          var dto = new ResponseBase<object>
          {
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Result = "ERROR",
            Summary = "Request was unsuccessful",
            Errors = new List<ErrorDescription>()
            {
              new ErrorDescription { Key = "Model validation failed", Errors = new List<string>() { "Request contains invalid model" } }
            },
            ResponseData = null
          };
          return new ObjectResult(dto){ StatusCode = 400 };
        };
      })
      .AddJsonOptions(o => { o.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true; });
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
    // Global exception handler
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
      try
      {
        await next();
      }

      catch (Exception e)
      {
        var dto = new ResponseBase<object>
        {
          Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
          Result = "ERROR",
          Summary = "Unexpected error",
          Errors = new List<ErrorDescription>()
          {
            new ErrorDescription { Key = "Unexpected error", Errors = new List<string>() { "Server encountered an unexpected error" } }
          },
          ResponseData = null
        };

        var result = new ObjectResult(dto) { StatusCode = 500 };
        await context.WriteObjectResult(result);
      }
    });
      
    // Global error status code middleware
    app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
    {
      var dto = new CustomErrorDto
      {
        Error = ReasonPhrases.GetReasonPhrase(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode),
        StatusCode = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode,
        RequestId = context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier
      };
      
      var result = new ObjectResult(dto) { StatusCode = dto.StatusCode };
      await context.HttpContext.WriteObjectResult(result);
    });
    
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });


    // Catch-all middleware for non-existing routes
    app.Use(next => async context =>
    {
      var dto = new ResponseBase<object>
      {
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Result = "ERROR",
        Summary = "Not found",
        Errors = new List<ErrorDescription>()
        {
          new ErrorDescription { Key = "Not found", Errors = new List<string>() { "The requested route does not exist" } }
        },
        ResponseData = null
      };
      
      var result = new ObjectResult(dto){ StatusCode = 404 };
      await context.WriteObjectResult(result);
    });
  }
}
```

However, this approach doesn't work if one of the controllers returns `NotFound()`. Then, the application returns the default `NotFound` response of .NET Core:

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "traceId": "00-74136ff6f453801ce1477aae7a24b428-01d02c424ae27d20-00"
}
```

Our ultimate goal: Everything that our server returns, must be in `BaseResponse` JSON format, no matter what happens during request processing. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the implementation of your BaseResponse class? And I can not find a single reference to your BaseResponse class in your code examples. Where should the BaseResponse be returned? Have you thought about a response class with a generic result data object? The calling applications just needs to know the generic type of the interface it is calling for deserialising the generic response.

Comment: as you can see, the default responses are already standardized.  I use a catchError function on the front-end to deal with them.

Comment: @rekcul I updated my question with the implementation of `ResponseBase` and how it is used in `Startup.cs`. However, as you can see in the case when controller returns `NotFound()`, none of the middlewares catch this error. This means that my API doesn't return a response in `ResponseBase` format in this case (there can maybe be more such undesired cases). My ultimate goal: **every** response that my API produces should be in the `ResponseBase` format, no matter what happens. This eases the deserialization process for the clients because they can always expect the same JSON structure.

Comment: @browsermator I would like to return a common JSON format for success and error API responses. This makes it much easier for clients to deserialize the response because the same format is always used.